# How can we display percentage in pie chart SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a Pie Chart in SSRS which has 4 Sectors with some number on them,i was planning to display percentages rather than displaying numbers.I tried Clicking on the Series Label properties and set the Label Data as #Percent.but percentage is displaying for only one sector and numbers to other sectors.

How can i display percentages for all the sectors?

Answer (score 2):

By default, the Series Label will return the Value for the Series. You can set it to format as a Percentage, but if the Value is 1, it is going to display 100%. To get the percentage Value over the Total Value, you'll need to modify the Label Data formula under the Series Label Properties.

1. Right Click the Series Label on your Chart.
2. Select Series Label Properties.
3. Enter this formula into the Label Data box, replacing your actual field and dataset names:

`=sum(Fields.YourValue.Value)/sum(Fields.YourValue.Value,"YourDataSet")`

Make sure you have selected "Percentage" under the Number Category on the Series Label Properties.

Let me know if you need more detail.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the UseValueAsLabel property of **EACH DATA SERIES** to false, and set the Label property to #PERCENT for EACH DATA SERIES.   The problem arises when using Visual Studio to edit the report, if you right click and choose "Show Data Labels" it only sets the first data series.  You need to right click on the chart and bring up the box with all the data series listed, and then click on each one and choose "Show Data Labels", and then change the properties in the property panel for that data series.
SQL Server 2012 Reporting Services, Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 0):

It should be: right click on the chart, select "Show data labels". 
Then right click on the label, Series label properties, select "#PERCENT" on the Label data drop down.